# Simple question about list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

Let

```
 list=Table[RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d}, 2], {4}]
```

> {{b, c}, {c, d}, {b, b}, {c, d}}

I want to get the following list  from the given `list`

$$\lbrace\sqrt{b^3+c^3},\sqrt{c^3+d^3}, \sqrt{b^3+b^3} , \sqrt{c^3+d^3}  \rbrace$$

How can I use [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) #&?

I tried something like this

```
 Sqrt[Plus @@ Map[#^3 &, list]]
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: `Sqrt[Plus @@@ (#^3)] &[list]` or  `Sqrt[Total[Transpose[#^3]]] &[list]`?

Comment: ...  or `☺ = +## & @@@ (#^3)^(1/2) &; ☺ @ list`:)

Comment: Sqrt[Plus @@ (#^3)] &/@ list

Answer (score 7):

```
☺ = √+## & @@@ (#^3) &;

☺ @ {{b, c}, {c, d}, {b, b}, {c, d}}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Also:

```
√Tr/@(#^3)& (* thanks: @Mr.Wizard *)
Sqrt[Total[#^3, {2}]] &
Sqrt[Total[Transpose[#^3]]] &
Sqrt[Plus @@@ (#^3)] &
```

Comment: Since you seem to have crafted this answer to please me (thanks!) you missed one of my favorites: `Tr`.  `Sqrt[Tr /@ (#^3)] &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, added the version with `Tr`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you don't to want get results like `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a^3]`;i.e., that you want two distinct cubic terms, I'm substituting `RandomSample` for `RandomChoice`.

```
SeedRandom[42];
MapThread[
  Sqrt[#1^3 + #2^3] &, 
  Transpose[Table[RandomSample[{a, b, c, d}, 2], {4}]]]
```

> `{Sqrt[b^3 + c^3], Sqrt[b^3 + d^3], Sqrt[a^3 + d^3], Sqrt[a^3 + c^3]}`

Answer (score 5):

Starting with your `list`

```
list = Table[RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d}, 2], {4}]

(* {{b, c}, {c, d}, {b, b}, {c, d}} *)
```

I often find it useful to break it down in steps.

**Step 1**. Compute the cube

```
Map[#^3 &, list]

(* {{b^3, c^3}, {c^3, d^3}, {b^3, b^3}, {c^3, d^3}} *)
```

**Step 2**. Apply `Plus`

Here is a brute force way to use `Map` on the previous output. `@@` is a shortcut for `Apply`.

```
Map[Plus @@ # &, Map[#^3 &, list]]

(* {b^3 + c^3, c^3 + d^3, 2 b^3, c^3 + d^3} *)
```

However there is a nice shortcut shown in **kglr**'s comment. `@@@` is a shortcut for `Apply` acting upon heads located at level 1.

```
Plus @@@ Map[#^3 &, list]

(* {b^3 + c^3, c^3 + d^3, 2 b^3, c^3 + d^3} *)
```

**Step** 3. Compute the square root

By now I think you get the idea. We will use `Map` to compute the square root of the outputs of step 2.

```
Map[Sqrt[#] &, Plus @@@ Map[#^3 &, list]]

(* {Sqrt[b^3 + c^3], Sqrt[c^3 + d^3], Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b^3], Sqrt[c^3 + d^3]} *)
```

In the notebook one sees

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Pure functions are counterproductive IMHO when constituent functions (i.e. `Power`) are Listable:

```
x = {{b, c}, {c, d}, {b, b}, {c, d}};

√( x^3 .{1,1} )
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[b^3 + c^3], Sqrt[c^3 + d^3], Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b^3], Sqrt[c^3 + d^3]}
> ```

In 2D notation:

[image]

I just realized that *Mathematica's* automatically copied expression was wrong.  My $x^3.\{1,1\}$ became `x^3.{1,1}` which parses as `(x^3.)*{1,1}` which of course doesn't work.  A space fixes this, which I added above, but I don't think the expression should have been copied this way.